# for loop and appending to an array in PHP

Tags: php, doctrine

I have the following code:

```
$items = array();

foreach($following as $storeOwner)
{
    array_push($items, $productRepository->mostRecentItem($storeOwner->getId(), 5));
}
```

I am trying to append the results of

```
 $productRepository->mostRecentItem($storeOwner->getId(), 5)
```

to `$items`. How do I do so? Why doesn't the above code work?

Comment: Did you debug what does $productRepository->mostRecentItem($storeOwner->getId(), 5) return ?

Comment: Logic is correct, Syntax is correct, Values might not be. What does your method return

Comment: if it is another array , array_merge will do the job

Comment: $productRepository->mostRecentItem($storeOwner->getId(), 5) must return string value.

Comment: What is the outcome? What doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$items = array();

foreach($following as $storeOwner)
{
    $items[] = $productRepository->mostRecentItem($storeOwner->getId(), 5);
}
```

Also, take a look to the result of the mostRecentItem Method... .

Answer (score 0):

**var_dump** you different objects and return values to make sure that contain what you think they should contain. The code looks "correct" so it's probably the objects and values that are not.